# Sqlite update row on unique value

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I am creating a table in sqlite3 from a csv file that supply's a unique id that i have to use. I have it to where i create the db and its complete. I am trying to take another csv file with the same unique id values but with added info that I want to apply to the db.

The csv file I want to add only apply's to so many of the rows in the db. I am getting a error: IndexError: list index out of range

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 62, in <module>
update_teams(x[0], x[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Am I getting this because there isn't the same amount of row on the csv to sqlite.db?

CSV format:

```
Id,PlayerName,TeamName
641393,John Doe1,Team1
663844,John Doe2,Team1
607469,John Doe3,Team1
```

My code:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

# connect to sqlite database
conn = sqlite3.connect('players.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# table values
table_spec = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players(
                player_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
                name_last TEXT,
                name_first TEXT,
                TeamName TEXT);"""


# Create Table
def create_table():
  c.execute(table_spec)


# Takes values and inserts them into the table
def write_core_data(player_id, name_last, name_first):
    c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE 
               INTO players ("player_id","name_last","name_first") 
               VALUES (?,?,?)', (player_id,name_last, name_first))
    conn.commit()


def update_teams(player_id, TeamName):
    c.execute('UPDATE players 
               SET TeamName=? 
               WHERE player_id=?',(TeamName, player_id))
    conn.commit()


# create_table()


with open('players_master.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for x in readCSV:
        write_core_data(x[0], x[1], x[2])
        print(x[0])

with open('team_list.csv') as teamlist:
    readCSV = csv.reader(teamlist, delimiter=',')
    for x in readCSV:
        update_teams(x[0], x[2])
        print("Added team {} to {}".format(x[2], x[1]))

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Well how large are these CSV files?  MBs?  GBs?

Comment: Thanks for the question. The db file is 6,793KB and the csv file is 334KB. So they are really small but i just figured since the amount of rows being different might be the issue.

Comment: SQLite (and most databases) don't work this way.  You don't run out of rows, certainly not with the small amount of data you have.  Can you highlight where exactly in the code the problem is happening?

Comment: Added blockcode for the complete error. The error is being created by the function update_teams(). Where i believe I have the correct syntax to raise the condition if the id is matched the team column is filled with the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, your cvs file has empty line(s) or a line that is too short.
Skip empty lines:

```
for x in readCSV:
    if x:
        update_teams(x[0], x[2])
```

You can also assert that `len(x) >= 3`:

```
for x in readCSV:
    if len(x) < 3:
        print('Skipping', x)
    else: 
        update_teams(x[0], x[2])
```

Comment: Yep this was the problem. Thank you for the solution!